# How to run-time click an arrayed command-button (by another arrayed or similar one) in vb6?

Tags: vb6, click, commandbutton

Run-time sending click command to a similar command-button named `cmd1` is so easy from another control:

```
 cmd1_Click
```

But this similar type not works when we're going to send this command from another form, there. For example by:

```
 Form2.cmd1_Click
```

Then for this time we used to write:

```
 Form2.cmd1.value = True
```

But now my question is for when this command-button is an array of controls. How we can code this doing one?

Comment: At a guess without a VB6 compiler at hand Form2.cmd1(0).value = True.  Or move your code from out of the event handler into a Public Sub and call the code from both your other form and the event handler.

Comment: Wow! Yes it works. but i had been test it, for several times before this time but the option of Value property doesn't shown in VS-helping dialog box, and now in this new test, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It was so useful to me!

Answer (score 0):

Comment turned to a an answer as the OP is happy with the response.

Equivalent for an array of controls is:

```
Form2.cmd1(0).value = True.
```

Or move your code from out of the event handler into a Public Sub and call the code from both your other form and the event handler